# Detecting duplicate tags

Tags: php, sql, tags

I have a site which allows users to openly tag their items before submitting, similar to what delicious.com does:

> ...users can tag each of their bookmarks
>   with freely chosen index terms...

I want to detect spelling mistakes and tags that are similar, or may belong to the same group.

For example, if someone tags something as Arsenal Football Club, this is the same as Arsenal FC, Arsenal, the Gooners, and/or the Gunners. I want to see which tag is used the most and then change it to that/ or create a group that encompasses all these tags, something like just Arsenal FC.

I have thouht about using the http://www.freebase.com/ API, or http://www.elasticsearch.org/ but these seem like overkill. I also know of something called [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collective_intelligence](http://collective%20intelligence).

Oh, and I'm using PHP and MySQL.

My table structure is as follows:

```
Item, Item_Tags, Tag
```

Basically being the lazy programmer that I am, has someone already done something like this, that I can <strike>just copy</strike> modify for my code?

What are your suggestions SO?

Comment: This is a very large and tedious task that you are trying to do. If you are the lazy programmer, as you say. Then you are out of luck. This can be done surely. People using stuff like Lucene which is a giant open source library that you can use. It has lots of stuff for allowing similar meaning of text like Arsenal -> football might be the same. It is a difficult task for sure, but doable. In simple terms on the WWW, it is called FullText searching.

Comment: ElasticSearch: "Search can be executed either using a simple, Lucene based query string or using an extensive JSON based search query DSL. ". I *will* do it if push comes to shove, but arrr, I'm too lazy to look up a quote about being lazy.

Comment: Better check it then! Some server must be running Lucene, it must be populated with your desired text, with the conditions set. Then only will querying it will work!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use the MySQL SOUNDS LIKE search:

```
SELECT id, tag FROM tags WHERE tag SOUNDS LIKE 'Shaw'
```

This wil give you also a tag like 'Saw'.